# How do you retrieve a list of of transactional templates from SendGrid?

Tags: asp.net-core, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

What is the correct usage for retrieving a list of transactional templates from the SendGrid API, the documentation doesn't seem correct.

https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/transactional-templates/retrieve-paged-transactional-templates

```
var response = await client.RequestAsync(
    method: SendGridClient.Method.GET,
    urlPath: "v3/templates,
    queryParams: queryParams
);
```

The above documentation states to call the `v3/templates` API endpoint to retrieve a list of transactional templates. But I'm receiving a `NotFound` response when calling it. Changing the `urlPath` to `templates` provides a `Forbidden` response. I know the API key I'm using is correct because I can send emails with the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

I had a quick look through the C# library and it seems that it does [put the `v3` into the URL itself](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/732dcc9874a4bd3c6b6930c5c6abd0a9da8ed049/src/SendGrid/BaseClient.cs#L288). So the example in the docs may well be wrong and I've alerted the team to this.

So, when you change the `urlPath` to just "templates" you then got a `Forbidden` error. With SendGrid, API keys can be scoped to just certain actions within the API, so being able to send an email with an API key does not imply that key also has the permissions to read templates. I would try creating a new API key that definitely has permission to read templates and see if your code works.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, it's weird in that I went to see if there are permissions on the API key and didn't notice anything. Went back just now and saw all the permissions, must have been blind! 

I gave read access for `Legacy Email Template` & `Template Engine` and now it's working . Would be good if the documentation also mentioned the required permissions.